# How many if else i can use?

Tags: php, if-statement

How many if else i can use ??

```
<?php
    if($d_1 == 'NULL')
       { 
?>
         <td align="center"><input type="date"  name="clas1" /><br/><input id="class1"    type="submit" name="c1" value="Submit" /></td>             
<?php        
    } 
    else        
    {  
?>      
      <td align="center"><span>Completed On <br/> <?php echo $d_1;?></span> </td>
<?php
    }       
    if($d_2 == 'NULL') 
    { 
?>
          <td align="center"><input type="date"  name="clas2" /><br/><input id="class2" type="submit" name="c2" value="Submit" /></td>

<?php 
    } 
    else 
    {  
?> 
      <td align="center"><span>Completed On <br/> <?php echo $d_2;?></span> </td> 
<?php 
    } 

    if($d_3 == 'NULL') 
    { 
?>
      <td align="center"><input type="date"  name="clas3" /><br/><input id="class3" type="submit" name="c3" value="Submit" /></td>            

<?php
    } 
    else 
    {  

?>    <td align="center"><span>Completed On <br/> <?php echo $d_3;?></span> </td> 

<?php 
    } 
    if($d_4 == 'NULL') 

        { 

?>
      <td align="center"><input type="date"  name="clas4" /><br/><input id="class4" type="submit" name="c4" value="Submit" /></td>            

<?php 
    } 
    else 
    {  

?>    <td align="center"><span>Completed On <br/> <?php echo $d_4;?></span> </td> 

<?php 
    }           
?>
```

i am fetching 4 dates from database which are: $d_1, $d_2, $d_3 & $d_4. I am checking each date with if-else condition. First 2 conditions are working fine but in 3rd and 4th condition only else part is being executed
any other way to do this ???
thanks..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: So you questions is, 'how many?' - as many as you like...

Comment: You are not restricted to 2, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @user2099014: Cloud you include `var_dump($d_1, $d_2, $d_3, $d_4);` please and post the output here.

Comment: FDL has already given you the correct answer to how many can you have, I have given you an alternative method and so has Broken Heart, either of which will achieve the same output whilst being more readable in your code.

Comment: @DerVO Output is string '2013-07-10' (length=10)
string '2013-07-02' (length=10)
string '2013-07-06' (length=10)
null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by making a simple function:

```
<?php

function fun($val,$num) {
      if(empty($val) || $val == 'NULL' || $val == 'null') {
         echo '<td align="center"><input type="date" name="class'.$num.'" /><br/><input id="class'.$num.'" type="submit" name="c'.$num.'" value="Submit" /></td>'; 
      } else {
         echo '<td align="center"><span>Completed On <br/>'.$val.'</span></td>';
      }
}

fun($d_1,"1");
fun($d_2,"2");
fun($d_3,"3");
fun($d_4,"4");

?>
```

By using this approach you can check multiple dates.

Comment: Same problem... $d_4 is NULL but still else part is executing !!!!

Comment: @user2099014 if `$d_4` will be null then else part will be execute as given in the condition. well check that is there any value in `$d_4` or not. if it has value then let me know.

Comment: string '2013-07-10' (length=10)
string '2013-07-02' (length=10)
string '2013-07-06' (length=10)
null   these are the values of all variables

Comment: @user2099014 as you can see in the last element the value is null means `$d_4` contains null value. simple that's why the else part is executing.

Comment: dear friend $d_4 is null so the if condition is true for $d_4 right ?? it should execute echo '<td align="center"><input type="date" name="class'.$num.'" /><br/><input id="class'.$num.'" type="submit" name="c'.$num.'" value="Submit" /></td>'; part... but it is executing the else part that what i want to know why ??? its giving output <td align="center"><span>Completed On <br/>'.$val.'</span></td> which is not true according to condition. Same thing happening for $d_3 if it is null.. I means that if else working for first two variable

Comment: @user2099014 I have updated the if condition. check now. hope it will work for you. if will work then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could try

```
<?php 
    for ($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
    {
        $varname = "d_$i";
        if (!isset($$varname) || $$varname == 'NULL')
            echo '<td align="center"><input type="date"  name="clas'.$i.'" /><br/><input id="class'.$i.'" type="submit" name="c'.$i.'" value="Submit" /></td>';
        else
            echo '<td align="center"><span>Completed On <br/> '.$$varname.'</span> </td>';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this structure instead:

```
if(condition){
}else if(condition){
}else if(condition){
}else{
}
```

Comment: No, this serves a different prupose. Note that each of the `if` blocks tests a different condition. `if/elseif` will produce different results!

Comment: @DarkBee Switch would not help here, each one is an atomic if / else if / else if / else rather than if elseif elseif elseif

Comment: yes, there are 4 variables that requires to be checked separately

Comment: As many as you need, you can use.